# 1 of 2 branches missed in Eclemma

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit4, eclemma

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate+jpa4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.

and this unit test

```
@Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
        List<Guardian> guardians = getGuardianAccessorService().findAll();
        assertNotNull (guardians);
        assertTrue    (guardians.size()>=0);
    }


@Test
    public void testFindCompanyGuardians() throws Exception {

        List<Guardian> allGuardians = getGuardianAccessorService().findAll();       
        List<Guardian> guardiansByCompany = getGuardianAccessorService().findCompanyGuardians(AUTHENTICATED_USERNAME);

        assertTrue    (guardiansByCompany.size() <= allGuardians.size());       
    }
```

but in this asserts lines I have the warning 1 of 2 branches missed

**assertTrue    (guardians.size()>=0);**

**assertTrue    (guardiansByCompany.size() <= allGuardians.size());**

Comment: Assuming `getGuardianAccessorService().findAll()` queries a database table, can you check whether that table has any records?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it makes sense to actually run branch (or line) coverage on your unit tests. You should mainly inspect your target under test, not the tests. It is expected that if your tests do not fail that the fail brach is not taken, and this is reported as partial coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it sees > and = as two different branches for the first assertTrue statement.

Comment: Show us the implementation of your answer